# MYSQL/SQLWave- Producing Distinct Data from Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

Currently I have two tables, `students` and `schools`. They're connected by a `school_id` (in `students`) and an `id` (in `schools`). If it means anything, this is from a cakePHP application with a MYSQL database and I'm  using SQLwave to run the query.

What I wish to do is produce a list of students who have their `graduation_year` listed as 2016 from specific schools. I used the following query, with the aims of producing the students' names, the name of their school, and graduation  year:

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.first_name, students.last_name, schools.name, students.graduation_year
FROM students JOIN schools
ON schools.id = students.school_id
WHERE schools.name = "Central City High School"
OR schools.name = "Gotham High School"
OR schools.name = "Metropolis High School"
OR schools.name = "Ivy Town High School"
AND students.graduation_year = 2016;
```

However, when I run the query I get a list of all of the students from these schools- but not only those who graduate in 2016 (I.E. I get those who have no listed graduation year, 2014, 2016, etc.). How can I improve this code to only show those who graduate in 2016? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `WHERE (schools.name = "Central City High School"
OR schools.name = "Gotham High School"
OR schools.name = "Metropolis High School"
OR schools.name = "Ivy Town High School")
AND students.graduation_year = 2016;`, or even better, `WHERE schools.name IN ("Central City High School", "Gotham High School", "Metropolis High School", "Ivy Town High School")
AND students.graduation_year = 2016;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `AND` goes before `OR` you have to put the schools.name conditions together within parentheses.

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.first_name, students.last_name, schools.name, students.graduation_year
FROM students JOIN schools
ON schools.id = students.school_id
WHERE (schools.name = "Central City High School"
       OR schools.name = "Gotham High School"
       OR schools.name = "Metropolis High School"
       OR schools.name = "Ivy Town High School")
  AND students.graduation_year = 2016;
```

However, using `IN` makes the code prettier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.first_name, students.last_name, schools.name, students.graduation_year
FROM students JOIN schools
ON schools.id = students.school_id
WHERE schools.name IN ("Central City High School", "Gotham High School",
                       "Metropolis High School", "Ivy Town High School")
  AND students.graduation_year = 2016;
```

Comment: That clears everything up, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You should group your conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.first_name, students.last_name, schools.name, students.graduation_year
FROM students JOIN schools
ON schools.id = students.school_id
WHERE 
(schools.name = "Central City High School"
OR schools.name = "Gotham High School"
OR schools.name = "Metropolis High School"
OR schools.name = "Ivy Town High School")
AND students.graduation_year = 2016
```